# OpenGL Texture is not rendered (C)

Tags: c, opengl, shader, textures

I want to render a simple picture between a rectangle (two triangles) but when I start the program, there is just a black rectangle instead of the picture.
To render the picture, I´m using shaders, which I acces with uniforms.
I can´t find a mistake, why It´s not rendering.
Could you please help me?

main.c

```
#define APIENTRY __stdcall
#include<glad/glad.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#include "VertexBuffer.h"
#include"shader2.h"
#include "index_buffer.h"
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"


struct VertexBuffer buffer1;
struct IndexBuffer indexBuffer1;
uint32_t numVerticies = 4;
uint32_t numIndices = 6;
int colorUniformLocation;
GLuint indexBuffer;
GLuint textureId;
float time = 0.0f;
float a = 0.0f;
float b = 0.0f;
float c = 0.0f;


void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(0,1.0,1.0,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //Löscht Bild aus Speicher

    bindVertexBuffer(&buffer1);
    bindIndexBuffer(&indexBuffer1);
    glUniform4f(colorUniformLocation, a, b, c, 1.0f);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    unbindVertexBuffer();
    unbindIndexBuffer(&indexBuffer1);

    glFlush(); //Gibt dem Bildschirm das Bild
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if(key == 27) //Wenn Escape schließen
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}

void reshape(int width, int height)
{

}

void update(int t)
{

    time+=0.02f;
    a = sinf(time) * sinf(time);
    b = cosf(time) * cosf(time);
    c = tanf(time) * tanf(time);

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1000.0/60.0, update, 0);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(183,100);
    glutCreateWindow("TestApp");
    glutDisplayFunc(display); //display func initialisieren
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard); //keyboard func initialisieren
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape); //reshape func initialisieren
    glutTimerFunc(1000.0/60.0, update, 0);

    gladLoadGL();

    //Initialize the triangle-------------------------
    struct Vertex verticies[6];
    verticies[0].x = -0.5;
    verticies[0].y = -0.5;
    verticies[0].z = 0;
    verticies[0].u = 0;
    verticies[0].v = 0;
    verticies[0].r = 1;
    verticies[0].g = 0;
    verticies[0].b = 0;
    verticies[0].a = 1;

    verticies[1].x = -0.5;
    verticies[1].y = 0.5;
    verticies[1].z = 0;
    verticies[0].u = 0;
    verticies[0].v = 1;
    verticies[1].r = 0;
    verticies[1].g = 1;
    verticies[1].b = 0;
    verticies[1].a = 1;

    verticies[2].x = 0.5;
    verticies[2].y = -0.5;
    verticies[2].z = 0;
    verticies[0].u = 1;
    verticies[0].v = 0;
    verticies[2].r = 0;
    verticies[2].g = 0;
    verticies[2].b = 1;
    verticies[2].a = 1;

    verticies[3].x = 0.5;
    verticies[3].y = 0.5;
    verticies[3].z = 0;
    verticies[0].u = 1;
    verticies[0].v = 1;
    verticies[3].r = 1;
    verticies[3].g = 0;
    verticies[3].b = 0;
    verticies[3].a = 1;

    uint32_t indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        1, 2, 3
    };
    //-------------------------------------------------


    initIndexBuffer(&indexBuffer1, indices, numIndices, sizeof(indices[0]));
    initVertexBuffer(&buffer1, verticies, numVerticies); //Buffer initialisieren

    char vs[] ="#version 330 \nlayout(location = 0) in vec3 a_position;\nlayout(location = 1) in vec2 a_texCoord;\nlayout(location = 2) in vec4 a_color;\nout vec4 v_color;\nout vec2 v_texCoord;\nvoid main()\n{\ngl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0f);\nv_color = a_color;\nv_texCoord = a_texCoord;\n}";
    char fs[] =  "#version 330\nlayout(location = 0) out vec4 f_color;\nin vec4 v_color;\nin vec2 v_texCoord;\nuniform sampler2D u_texture;\nuniform vec4 u_color;\nvoid main()\n{\nvec4 texColor = texture(u_texture, v_texCoord);\nf_color = texColor;\n}";

    int32_t textureWidth = 0;
    int32_t textureHeight = 0;
    int32_t bitsPerPixel = 0;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    auto textureBuffer = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\Maciel\\Desktop\\Backup_Maciel\\c_coding\\Testing_glut\\res\\logo.png", &textureWidth, &textureHeight, &bitsPerPixel, 4);

    //TEXTURE------------------------------------

    glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    if(textureBuffer)
    {
        stbi_image_free(textureBuffer);
    }

    //Shader laden------------------------------
    struct Shader shader1;
    initShader(&shader1, vs, fs);
    bindShader(&shader1);

    colorUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader1.shaderId, "u_color");
    if(!colorUniformLocation != -1)
    {
        glUniform4f(colorUniformLocation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    int textureUnifromLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader1.shaderId, "u_texture");
    if(!textureUnifromLocation != -1)
    {
        glUniform1i(textureUnifromLocation, 0);
    }

    //LOOP starts
    glutMainLoop();

    cleanUpVertexBuffer(&buffer1);
    cleanUpIndexBuffer(&indexBuffer1);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &textureId);

    return 0;
}
```

VertexBuffer.h

```
#include<glad/glad.h>

struct Vertex
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    float u;
    float v;

    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
    float a;
};

struct VertexBuffer
{

    //Parameter
    void* data;
    uint32_t numVerticies;

    GLuint bufferID;
    GLuint vao;
};

void initVertexBuffer(struct VertexBuffer *buffer, void *d, uint32_t nV)
{
    (*buffer).data = d;
    (*buffer).numVerticies = nV;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &(buffer->vao)); //Vao wird erzeugt, id = vao
    glBindVertexArray((*buffer).vao); //Vao wird gebindet

    glGenBuffers(1, &(buffer->bufferID)); //Buffer/Speicher wird erzeugt -> Anzahl an VBO´s
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (*buffer).bufferID); //Buffer wird gebindet -> ist ein Array
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (*buffer).numVerticies * sizeof(struct Vertex), (*buffer).data, GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Daten werden in Buffer geschrieben

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); //Aktiviert index 0 vom vao
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct Vertex), 0); //Sagt wie OpemGL die Daten interpretieren soll

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct Vertex), 12);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct Vertex), 20);
    glBindVertexArray(0); //vao wird geunbindet
}

void bindVertexBuffer(struct VertexBuffer *buffer)
{
    glBindVertexArray((*buffer).vao);
}

void unbindVertexBuffer()
{
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void cleanUpVertexBuffer(struct VertexBuffer *buffer)
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, (*buffer).bufferID);
}
```

shader2.h

```
#include<glad/glad.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct Shader
{
    //Parameter
    const char *vertexShader;
    const char *fragmentShader;

    GLuint shaderId;
};

GLuint createShader();
GLuint compileShader();

void initShader(struct Shader *shader, const char *vS, const char *fS)
{
    (*shader).vertexShader = vS;
    (*shader).fragmentShader = fS;

    (*shader).shaderId = createShader((*shader).vertexShader, (*shader).fragmentShader);
}

void bindShader(struct Shader *shader)
{
    glUseProgram((*shader).shaderId);
}

void unBindShader()
{
    glUseProgram(0);
}

GLuint createShader(const char *vertexShader, const char *fragmentShader)
{
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    GLuint vs = compileShader(vertexShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fs = compileShader(fragmentShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

   //glDetachShader(program, vs);
   // glDetachShader(program, fs);

    return program;
}

GLuint compileShader(char *shaderSource, GLenum type)
{
    GLuint id = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &shaderSource, 0);
    glCompileShader(id);

    GLint result;
    glGetShaderiv(id,GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

    if(result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);

        GLchar *strInfoLog[length ];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, strInfoLog);
        fprintf(stderr, strInfoLog);
    }

    return id;
}
```

vertexshader

```
#version 330 
layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 a_texCoord;
layout(location = 2) in vec4 a_color;
out vec4 v_color;
out vec2 v_texCoord;
void main()
{
gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0f);
v_color = a_color;
v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

fragmentshader

```
#version 330
layout(location = 0) out vec4 f_color;
in vec4 v_color;
in vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec4 u_color;
void main()
{
vec4 texColor = texture(u_texture, v_texCoord);
f_color = texColor;
}
```

Comment: Why haven't you set the u and v coordinates of vertices 1,2, and 3?  Also, are you sure that you enter the vertices of the two triangles in you index buffer in counter clockwise direction.  It appears to me that the ordering 0, 1, 2 is in clock-wise winding.

Answer (score 2):

You are only setting vertex 0's texture coordinates:

```
verticies[0].u = 1;
verticies[0].v = 1;
```

You should also set them to verticies[1], verticies[2] and verticies[3]